# How to store data from a async function in a new array?

Tags: javascript, json, async-await

I'm pretty new to this and I'm stuck. I try to understand how I can store data from a json file in a new variable. I can log this out to the console, but I want to get this array in a new variable. Every video or tutorial I watched just did that... logs it out to the console.

Here is my code

```
const getData = async () => {

    const response = await fetch ('data.json');
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
    
};

getData()
    .then((data)=> console.log(data));
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might ask yourself **why** you want to store it in a variable. It's almost always an anti-pattern. Just chain asynchronous operations until you do some side-effect with the final result (call a database, call an API, update the DOM or anything else)

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I thought that i  have to chain all asynchs. I want to make something like a card a game where the data is put in from an external file. I guess in this case I should simply make a class for every deck as a js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, but as @Guerric P mentioned in the comments, you probably must ask yourself why you need to do this

```js
const getData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch ('data.json');
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
    
};

const putDataToVariable = async () => {
  const variable = await getData()
  console.log(variable)
}

putDataToVariable().then()
```

Comment: I guess OP wanted a variable defined in the outer scope. This is pointless anyway

Comment: He didn't mention that) And... its useless) unless it triggers some side effect